# Set an env variable using a CLI tool before launching the debugger in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks, delve

I have a Go application which uses a Postgres DB on Cloud (Heroku) and sets the DB Url as an environment variable calling the Heroku CLI as per guidelines.

So the app can be launched with the command

```
DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my-db) my-app
```

Now I would like to launch the app from within VSCode in debug mode but I do not find the right way to set the `DATABASE_URL` variable before the debug starts. I have tried with `preLaunchTask` but with no success. The configurations I have used with `preLaunchTask` are these

**launch.json**

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "preLaunchTask": "setPostgresDbUrl",
      "program": "${fileDirname}",
      "env": {},
      "args": []
    }
  ]
 }
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "setPostgresDbUrl",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "bash ./setUrl.sh"
    }
  ]
}
```

setUrl.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a go-batch)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem. My current understanding is that the task will run in its own process, and so modifying that environment variable in that script will not affect the launch process env.

Comment: @Zachary Rhodes I have added an answer to describe the way I have solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve the problem in a slightly different way, i.e. using an `.env` file to set an environment variable from which the url is read.

So, in the root folder of the project I have an `.env` file like this

```
 the url may change - to get the current url run the command 
# echo $(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a go-batch)

DATABASE_URL=postgres://blah-blah-1.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/blah
```

Then in the `launch.json` I specify to read the environment variable values like this

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "LaunchGo",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      //"preLaunchTask": "setPostgresDbUrl",
      "program": "${fileDirname}",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```